# Problems installing Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

When trying to run a joomla website I am giving a long list of the following strict standards erros(the list is like a hundred lines long:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 29
```

In php.ini error_reporting is set to E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE and that does not help.

Joomla version is very outdated - 1.5.18 and php version is 5.4.7

Comment: did you restart your apache after changin php.ini?

Comment: You really should not be running Joomla 1.5 on a PHP 5.4 website. Joomla 1.5 is ancient. Please consider upgrading to Joomla 2.5, which is the long term release, else to Joomal 3.0 (STR). Out of all honesty, I have no idea why you are trying to install Joomla 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla 1.5 supports PHP 4, it's going to have a ton of strict errors with php 5.3+.  As suggested above you can simply change you error reporting level not to show them, you can go back down a version or two of php like to 5.2.x or you can migrate to a currently supported version of Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla's configuration.php file, change $error_reporting value to 6135.

If this doesnt help you can add these lines to your .htaccess file:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```

But i do not recommend this method as it's hiding errors completely